# Isolated critical point implies non-degenerate?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I just proved using Morse lemma that every non-degenerate critical point of a $\cal{C}^2$ function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ is an isolated critical point.

Now I thinking whether the converse is true. That is, if $a$ is an isolated critical point, then it is a non-degenerate critical point?

I think it's not true, but I'm having a hard time figuring an example to show this. Can anyone provide me with an example or means to get one?

Answer (score 2):

$n   =   1$ and $y   =   x^3$?